# How should we respond to the Jewish expression "Shabbat Shalom"?

Tags: practical-islam, ahlul-kitab, jews, greetings

What should we answer to a Jew, when he tells us:
"שַׁבָּת שָׁלוֹם
(Shabbat Shalom)"?

Comment: The traditional greeting among Jews is shalom aleichem, peace unto you; to which the response is aleichem shalom, to you, peace.

When Jews say “Shabbat shalom – Sabbath peace” to family and friends after a draining work week, they mean far more than “have a peaceful and restful day.” What they are really saying is: May you be restored to wholeness on the blessed Sabbath!